# making an android app allows admin account to store and send data to members

Tags: android, ruby-on-rails, database

I'm new to programming I don't know which programming language I should 
use to make this database

I want to make an android app that allows users to register with an account and make a profile which contains data (points,meetings,etc) the admin account control it for each user the users I need about **100 users**
I searched for that and found (rails,firebase,www.parse.com)
can I use any thing of them ?

thanx in advance

Comment: Though, I answered you question, this is not  right place for this kind of question. I suggestion is, find a good developer for your work.

Answer (score 0):

You need `java` for implementing android application(also there are many options like you can make app using html, JavaScript, c#). If you want to store user information of-course need web app where you save user data that admin can access. For making web app you can use `Ruby on Rails` also has other so many technologies. For sending messages to user ( that will send admin) you need push notification and `parse.com` help you to do this.

Comment: thanx for answer it was very helpful . Then I should look for Ruby on Rails.
can I make editing the data from the android app directly or use it to modify the data on the web?

Comment: Just think, all downloaded apps are installed on user phone then how do you get those data for edit? Of course we have to keep those data some where where you (admin) has access.